# Visual Studio Command Line Build in Release always produces DLL's in Debug

Tags: build, visual-studio-2017, release, devenv

This just started happening without any changes.  From inside Visual Studio, it builds correctly but from the command line even though I'm specifying release the DLL's are still being build in Debug.

First I'm calling:

devenv.com MySolution.sln /Clean

Next, I call

devenv.com MySolution.sln /rebuild Release

Is it possible some update has caused this, I feel like I'm exhausted all measures to resolve this?  We are unable to deploy because we can not build in release mode.

I've tried, deleting everything and doing a fresh get from TFS
Rebooted the PC
Checked for updates
Reinstalled Visual Studio

Comment: Testing other solutions shows it's only a problem with the one solution so it must be related to the solution file.

Comment: Ok found some more clues. After I build the solution then I publish some websites.  It appears that when this happens it's rebuilding the solution again in debug mode.  It didn't use to do this, not sure why this started happening.